# amChart failed to initialize after modal is show

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog, amcharts

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: route,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $('#evolutieProdus').show();
            function showEvProd(data){                                          
                var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart_2",{
                "type": "serial",
                  "theme": "dark",                     
                  "dataProvider" : data,
                  "valueAxes": [ {
                    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "gridAlpha": 0.2,
                    "dashLength": 0
                  } ],
                  "gridAboveGraphs": true,
                  "startDuration": 1,
                  "graphs": [ {
                    "balloonText": "[[date]]: <b>[[bucati]] bucati vandute </b>",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "type": "column",
                    "valueField": "bucati"
                  } ],
                  "chartCursor": {
                    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                    "cursorAlpha": 0,
                    "zoomable": false
                  },
                  "categoryField": "date",
                  "categoryAxis": {
                    "gridPosition": "start",
                    "gridAlpha": 0,
                    "tickPosition": "start",
                    "tickLength": 20
                  },
                  "export": {
                    "enabled": true
                  }             
                }); 
            }
            showEvProd(response);
            console.log(response);              
        },
        error: function(){
            toastr.error('Eroare, ceva nu a functionat corect, reveniti mai tarziu');
        }       
    });
```

This is my ajax call. I receive the callback with the data but in the graph all I see is an undefined. What is wrong with my code .
P.S. If I hard-coding the dataProvider object it works. But I want to load the graph with the data provided by the server via the ajax response.

Comment: First: Initializing the chart after the data is returned doesn't seem like the best solution for me here. Just set `chart.dataProvider = data` in the success handler and then call `chart.validateData()`.
Apart from that I don't see any configuration mistakes you made. Are you sure the data is returned in the correct format? Maybe you can post the result of your request. (Or parts of it)

Comment: Yes.The error was on the data format. The function parseJSON() resolved the problem.Thanks for your advice.